# AngularJS own factory and ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have create my own LoggerService but if I use it I get error:

```
FOrder.query is not a function
```

If i remove all LoggerService calls in controller all work fine, why i can't use LoggerService?
services.js

```
angular.module('GSAdmin.services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('FOrder', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/order/:orderId');
    }])
   .service('LoggerService', [function(){
        var _logList = [];
        this.getLast = function(){
            return _logList[_logList.length-1];
        };
        this.getLog = function(){
            return _logList;
        };
        this.log = function(text) {
           _logList.push(text);
        };
}])
```

controller.js

```
    .controller('OrderController', ['$scope', 'FOrder', 'LoggerService',
        function($scope, FOrder, LoggerService) {
            FOrder.query(function(data){
                 $scope.orders = data;
        });

        $scope.log = LoggerService.getLog();
        LoggerService.log('Begin editing order #' + field.id);

    }]);
```

Comment: It looks like you have an extra closing curly brace at the end of your service definition.

Comment: It's wrong cutting for post here. I fix question.

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('OrderController', ['$scope', 'FOrder', 'LoggerService',      function($scope, FOrder, LoggerService) {
            FOrder.query(function(data){
                 $scope.orders = data;
        });

        $scope.log = LoggerService.getLog();
        LoggerService.log('Begin editing order #' + field.id);
} <-- **you missed that bracket**
    ]);
```

Comment: Nope, please don't look to bracers. I Cut some not needed code and make mistakes in bracers. If i really miss bracers, console log will write about it.

Comment: please see here http://jsbin.com/xafiq/1/edit  otherwise there is no more errors, you add to this bin all your code that will helps us to figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in 'FOrder', 'LoggerService',  i dont know why is important, but when i switch it to 'LoggerService', 'FOrder', all fine work.